# DIs there any method to create my own sources.list file for Ubuntu and make it work well?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

In order to use my local .deb packages, I have to alter the file "/etc/apt/sources.list" as follows:

```
deb file:/home/mary mydebs/
```

The line above means that the repository is my local directory /home/mary/mydebs in which include all my .deb packages.

But I cannot do this operation and execute "apt-get update" command because I cannot get root right. Now I want to create my own sources.list under any suitable directory such as /home/mary/ and make it work like what /etc/apt/source.list does. Is there any method?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by "I cannot get root right"? You should be the root and you can't gain it back or the root it someone else?

Comment: If you are following a HOWTO or something to build your local repository can you give us the link, and tell us where you are having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tools are you using to build your local repository, or are you using any tools yet?

A list of tools and some documentation can be found in the [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository).  There is also the [old repository HOWTO](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto) which is worth reading to get an idea of some of the concepts.  The most basic tool is [dpkg-scanpackages](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=dpkg-scanpackages), which is a tool that looks through a tree of Debian  binary  packages and creates the required Packages file.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you had your own `sources.list`, `apt-get` or `aptitude` still needed to access files in `/var/lib/dpkg/` which are only accessible for the superuser.

If it's your system, use `sudo` or `su` to gain superuser privileges. If it's not your system it's probably better if you don't.

Comment: I am 90% sure that Mary isn't talking about privileges, rather the difficulty is formatting the sources.list line correctly to point at a local repository, or perhaps properly structuring the repository.

Comment: Yes, I am not talking about privileges. I cannot change the fact that I am not the root and I even cannot use sudo to gain superuser privileges. Because this is the limitation my company provide. I mainly refer to the manual in the website: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/index.en.html#contents.

Comment: I generate my own .deb package by consulting chapter 4 of this manual. Then create my own repository and edit sources.list as the steps introduced in chapter 2.2 of this manual. It indeed adpot the tool dpkg-scanpackages. But I cannot edit /etc/apt/sources.list because privilege problem.

Comment: So I have the question if there is method to create my own sourses.list file in other directory and it has the same effect with the original sourses.list in directory /etc/apt. Then I will have the write privileges to this file.

Comment: No, there isn't. As I already said: You don't have the necessary privileges as a normal user. You need superuser privileges for that kind of action.